# Averaging the output of multiple processes in C

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I've been searching around about the topic, but it's kinda confusing for me with how many different techniques there are and I'm not sure how to approach my problem.

I have a function that computes some value, but it's based on random numbers and I want to compute that value multiple times, let's say few dozen or hundred times and take the average of it, but since it takes quite a while I've wanted to use multiprocessing, with each process executing that function, saving the result and then I'd simply sum the results and divide by the amount of worker processes in the main process.

Quite simple in theory, but I have no idea how to do it - it seems that a simple way would be to just do something like

```
loop that creates pipes
if (fork())
    loop that reads the outputs of pipes
else
    code of function that computes the desired value
```

but that somehow seems wrong? I'm really not sure how to do it

EDIT: 
To adress the comments, I've been thinking about something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n_children; ++i) {
        if (fork() == 0) { //child process
            x += estimation();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n_children; ++i)    //waiting for each process to end
        wait(NULL);

    x /= n_children;
```

but I know that it won't work properly, I don't know how to store/synchronize the results

Comment: `fork()` creates a new process, not a thread...

Comment: Look into OpenMP for the easiest way to write multi-threaded code. And make sure your RNG is thread-safe and that each thread has a different seed.

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered here. Can you show us if you had made any attempt using threads and if you have a specific problem implementing it?

Comment: May I know how many threads you would like to create?? Fork() will spawn a new process, whereas to create new thread use "Pthreads" i.e. POSIX threads. check POSIX threads  man page by entering the command "man pthread_create"

Comment: Running your program with GNU `parallel` might also be an option.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Added the code as an edit, couldn't make it look decent as a comment

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaBellamkonda my bad, I meant to do this by processes, with amount of them being a variable

Comment: You only need one pipe.  Create the pipe, spawn some children.  Each child writes a value into the pipe.  One process (perhaps the parent) reads all the values and computes the average.  It's much easier to do all the parallelization at the shell level, though.

Comment: @Monkae, you meant to say that each process should generate a random number and will store the random numbers in their respective buffer. After all child process completes their random generation task, the parent should take the result and compute the average. Is that what you want?

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaBellamkonda I think? I'm not sure what you mean by stroing numbers in buffers, but besides that yeah, I want each child to compete the task and then for parent to get every result and get the average. The problem i have is how to store and collect the results, but it was already answered by James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) mentioned in the comments, a single pipe is what you want.  The parent will close the write end, and each forked child will close the read end.  Each child writes its result to the pipe.  The parent calls **wait**(2) on each child and, if the status indicates data was written to the pipe, reads the pipe and updates the average.

It could also be done with Posix anonymous shared memory.  Allocate an array of results in shared memory.  Each child will have a unique value of the loop variable `i` when its process is created.  The child writes to `array[i]`. The parent waits for each child.  When they have all completed, iterate over the array and compute.